# OpenGL white blank screen and not responding

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I am using SDL2.00 with OpenGL to create a program. The program isn't supposed to do anything at the moment it's just a test bed. However I ran into a problem. When I create a window using SDL_CreateWindow, the window goes into a busy state and stops responding. The program flow isn't really affected by this however the window itself just won't work. All it does is show a white blank window and accept no input, can't resize can't move and can't quit. I will attach the code but I doubt it is code related since I already made a few programs using SDL and they seem to work just fine.

Using VS2013 SDL2.00 OpenGL

=========main========

```
#include "stdafx.h"


void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45, 640.0 / 480.0, 1.0, 500.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

}

void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f(0.0, 2.0, -5.0);
glVertex3f(-2.0, -2.0, -5.0);
glVertex3f(2.0, -2.0, -5.0);
glEnd();

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){


SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); 
SDL_Window * window;
window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGLTest", 300, 300, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN |       SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
init();


while (true){
    display();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}




return 0;

}
```

=========stdafx======

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

using namespace std;
```

Comment: How far have you debugged this? Do you enter your main loop? Do you enter your draw loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to process all the events, so the SDL window is just waiting and waiting and waiting, thereby *"not responding"* - Simply adding that should fix the problem!

```
while (true) {
    SDL_PumpEvents();

    display();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
}
```

You could also pull all the events manually with a loop calling `SDL_PollEvent(SDL_Event *event)`

```
SDL_Event event;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    // Process the event...
}
```

#### Wiki

- `SDL_PumpEvents()` - http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents
- `SDL_PollEvent()` - http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent

Comment: lol... thank you so much. that did the trick. I knew i was missing something so stupid! again thank you! the thing is now its just a white space. there should be a triangle but i dont see it. and also the background should be cleared with black that doesnt happen either.

Comment: You're welcome, and that probably have something to do with the vertices and matrices!